# "sony theme-creator-v1_5_0" isn't installing

Tags: sony

every time I'm trying to install the application shows me the same error.

The error message is
 **"Failed to increase memory of application.
 Application performance may suffer as result.
 *Cause:* java.lang.RuntimeException: JVM exit code: 0"**

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error in version 2.0.1. Fixed issue when running with cmd.

```
java -jar theme-creator-v2_0_1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

JAVA 9.0.1 do not support sony theme creator 1.5,Unless you have a program code that can be modified, you can only wait for a new theme creator version.

Or install the less than JAVA 9.0,and try again.

I've been resolve the error all day.

In Java 9 “Application and extension class loaders are no longer instances of java.net.URLClassLoader”